# How to return rows from multiple tables selected from information_schema

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

I need to return rows from a set of tables found in `information_schema`. I can find the table names, and I have a function that compiles and executes, but it returns an empty set, so there must be something wrong with my logic.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_prices() 
  RETURNS TABLE(price FLOAT) AS $func$
    DECLARE
      tn TEXT;
      BEGIN
        FOR tn in SELECT table_name 
          FROM information_schema.tables 
          WHERE table_name ~~ '%price%'  
          AND table_schema ~~ 'stg0' LOOP
            EXECUTE 'SELECT price FROM stg0.' || tn;
          END LOOP;
      END;
  $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I execute the following

```
SELECT * FROM get_prices();
```

I get a table with no rows and a single column, `price`.

The `SELECT` in the `FOR` loop is returning all the needed table names. There are many rows in those tables in the `price` column. What should change to return those rows?

*UPDATE*: I should have made it more clear that I have a large, undetermined number of source tables for the query at compile time, so I was looking to query the `information_schema` at runtime in order to pull the source table names dynamically.

The given query works and actually returns data by replacing the `EXECUTE` line with

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT price FROM stg0.' || tn;
```

as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Probably needs `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's 0-fun. Just generate one statement using `UNION ALL` and now you don't need cursors.

```
CREATE TABLE foo_1(price) AS VALUES (1);
CREATE TABLE foo_2(price) AS VALUES (1);
CREATE TABLE foo_3(price) AS VALUES (1);

SELECT STRING_AGG(
  FORMAT(
    'SELECT price FROM %I.%I.%I',
    table_catalog,
    table_schema,
    table_name
  ), ' UNION ALL ') ||';'
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name like '%foo_%';
```

You can put it in a function like this (first we get the result as a query string, and then we execute it)

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_prices()
RETURNS setof int AS $func$
  DECLARE
    sql text := string_agg(
      FORMAT(
        'SELECT price::int FROM %I.%I.%I',
        table_catalog,
        table_schema,
        table_name
      ), ' UNION ALL ') ||';'
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name like '%foo_%';
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;
  END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As a special note, if the list of `table_name ~~ '%price%'  AND table_schema ~~ 'stg0'` is immutable (that means you're not still adding to it) you're better of doing this one time and saving it as a `VIEW`

Comment: That is elegant. I was thinking about a `UNION` but didn't have the structure that you have. However, I didn't make it clear enough that I have a large and dynamic set of tables that I'm working with, so pre-compiling the list is not the way to go. Is there a way to build up the `UNION ALL` approach with `table_names` coming from the appropriate `SELECT`?

Comment: @ShawnMehan that's what this does, every time you `SELECT * FROM foo()` you get a new query.

Comment: This isn't working for me for my query, but that could be other issues, and I see the art in the structure. Thanks for the enlightenment.